# Run str_replace once / Encrypter&Decrypter

Tags: php

I'm making simple Decrypter/Encrypter with `str_replace`. But I have one problem.
For example, the code is:

```
$this->Text->text = str_replace("a", "b", $this->Text->text);

$this->Text->text = str_replace("b", "c", $this->Text->text);
```

Lets imagine we have text "ab" in `$this->Text->text`. But when I run the code, it outputs "cc". I need it to output "bc". What's the problem?

Comment: Exchange the two instructions. First replace `b` to `c` then `a` to `b`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I hope it will work, I'll try.

Comment: No way to work. I'll try to add another text field. Thx for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such job (transliteration) you have to use [strtr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$str =  "abc bca cab"; 
echo strtr($str, 'abc', 'bca');
```

**Output:**

```
bca cab abc
```

Comment: @ya_Bob_Jonez: Then, what is your needs? Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1430576/edit) and explain what you're trying to achieve with significant test cases.

Comment: Why are you answering off topic questions?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem resolved!**

### SOLUTION:

Added second Text field. From one field changes to text and outputs in another.